# Not understanding the concept of relation union (Set Theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $(C,S)$ be a well-ordered set, and $d \notin C$.

We define the set $D=C \cup \{d\}$ with the relation $S'=S \cup (C \times \{d\})$

Show that $(D,S')$ is well ordered.

--

I don't understand what the union of $S$ with $(C \times \{d\})$ actually mean... what does it mean two elements are in this relation?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $S$ is a set of ordered pairs, and $S\subseteq C\times C$. We want to define a relation on $C\cup\{d\}$, then it needs to be a subset of $(C\cup\{d\})\times(C\cup\{d\})$.

$S$ satisfies that property, since it is a subset of $C\times C$, but then $S$ is not an well-order relation on $C\cup\{d\}$. So we need to say something on how does $d$ and the rest of the elements are comparable. So we add all the ordered pairs $(c,d)$ where $c\in C$, meaning we declare that $d$ is the maximum of the new order.

But what does it mean that we add all the pairs $(c,d)$ to $S$? It means that we take the set of all such pairs, $\{(c,d)\mid c\in C\}$ and take its union with $S$. And what is this set? It is $C\times\{d\}$.